# MS Access: Duplicates with distinct values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database with hundred thousands of objects with geographical coordinates and multiple columns. I am trying to find duplicates by following criteria:

1. Lattitudes of two objects should coincide;
2. Longitudes of two objects should coincide;
3. Values of column "Object_Number" of two objects should not coincide with each other;
4. Value of column "Object_Number" of any of two objects in pair shouldn't equal "-".

I have already found the groups of duplicates by coincidence of lattitude and longitude by the standard tools of Microsoft Access. The code is:

```
SELECT ['Database].Latitude, ['Database].Longitude,  ['Database].Object_Number
FROM ['Database]
WHERE (((['Database].Latitude) In (SELECT [Latitude] FROM ['Database] As Tmp GROUP BY [Latitude],[Longitude] HAVING Count(*)>1  And [Longitude] = ['Database].[Longitude])))
ORDER BY ['Database].Latitude, ['Database].Longitude;
```

Result of query seems so:

[image]

But it should seem so:

[image]

What should i add to my code to fulfill criteria 3 and 4?

Comment: Should post data as formatted text tables, not images. Cannot copy/pasted images. And/Or provide SQL to create and populate tables.

Comment: Why does table name have apostrophe?

Comment: Review https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support. And an on-line tool https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: Is Object_Number a number or text field? Is hyphen actually in field or is this indicating Null?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Object_Number is actually Null where hyphen shown in sample, consider:

Query1:

```
SELECT [Latitude] & [Longitude] AS D
FROM Data
GROUP BY [Latitude] & [Longitude], [Object_Number]
HAVING (((Count(Object_Number))>1))
```

Query2:

```
SELECT [Latitude] & [Longitude] AS D
FROM Data
WHERE ((([Latitude] & [Longitude]) 
IN (SELECT Latitude & Longitude FROM Data WHERE Object_Number IS NULL)));
```

Query3:

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE 
NOT Latitude & Longitude IN (SELECT D FROM Query1) AND 
NOT Latitude & Longitude IN (SELECT D FROM Query2);
```